# OnRender and background superposition

Tags: .net, wpf

I draw some drawings in the `OnRender` method of a WPF user control. Now, I set a white background, and I see thebackground is over my drawing, so it is not visible anymore. How to put the drawing OVER the background?

```
  Protected Overrides Sub OnRender(drawingContext As DrawingContext)
    MyBase.OnRender(drawingContext)

    If Me._DisplayMargin Then
      Me.DrawMargin(drawingContext)
    End If

  End Sub
```

Comment: Is it simply the order in which you're rendering?  Can we see the code?

Comment: @Phil, done, inside the DrawMargin I do something like `drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, myPen, myMarginRectangle)`

Comment: @Phil, see my previous comment.

Comment: As Phil says, your drawing order is wrong. Call DrawMargin() before base.OnRender()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that OnRender doesn't work well with a WPF UserControl, See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/94ddd25e-7093-4986-b8c8-b647924251f6) why. The order in which you call `base.OnRender` doesn't matter (and of course you did right with calling it before your own rendering code, because you want to draw *over* things that might have been drawn by the base class).

If you're going to do all drawing in OnRender, you should simply derive from `FrameworkElement` instead of `UserControl`.

Comment: I need to add children on that MyUserControl... So I need something like UserControl... a container...

Comment: Then you could perhaps add the derived FrameworkElement as an extra child (before the others) to your UserControl. Or use a [DrawingBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingbrush.aspx) for the UserControl's `Background`.